# simple regex question: SQL (extract values before space)

Tags: regex

Data: `Mumbai, India (June 8 2019)`

---

1. using the below code I have extracted `June 8` from above data:

   `Regexp_replace(Extract_Regexp("Mumbai, India (June 8)" ,r"\((.*)$"),r"\)(.*)","")`
2. Then extracted `8` from `"June 8"` using below code:

`Extract_Regexp("June 8" ,r"\ (.*)$")`

**Now I want to convert final output: 08/06/2019**

Comment: So what's your question exactly ?

Comment: Add some more sample data and its expected result. (Formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Looks like BigQuery. To get `June 8`, you may as well use a single `Extract_Regexp("...", r"\(([^()]+)\)$")`

Comment: @TheWildHealer my question is to create a date and month from `Mumbai, India (June 8)`  i.e `08/06/2019`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Using my code I am able to extract `June 8` now I want to extract `June`

Comment: To get just `June`, use `Extract_Regexp("...", r"\((\w+).*\)$")`.  Instead of `\w+` you may also use `\S+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code is not working, sharing my code which help me to extract `8` from `June` code: `Extract_Regexp("June 8" ,r"\ (.*)$")`

Comment: `\((\S+).*\)$` can't fail to work unless the engine does not support shorthands.  Try ``\(([^ ]+).*\)$`` instead then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be you get some idea.

```
[^\d ]+

    Match value:
    1.  june
```

https://rubular.com/r/3OR5xSF1gE1rrt